# swift 3: How to center align (vertically & horizontally) UIButton on UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to create an image UIButton and set its position programmatically vs using Interface Builder. The reason being I'll be showing/hiding the button based on some logic in ViewController. However, i've spent the past ~4hrs searching to no avail. I have tried following approaches:

1. Constraints: seemingly the recommended method
2. Setting UIButton.center property to `CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2)`

Here's the full code:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController{
    //this is here so i can access playButton across different functions that i'll define in this ViewController
    let playButton:UIButton = {
      let play_btn = UIButton()
        play_btn.setImage(UIImage(named:"my_button_image.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        play_btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return play_btn
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()


       playButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.toggle), for: .touchDown)
       let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.playButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
       let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.playButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

       self.view.addConstraints([centerX, centerY])

       view.addSubview(playButton)

    }
}
```

I've also tried doing: `playButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2)`

as well as:

`playButton.center.x = self.view.center.x
 playButton.center.y = self.view.center.y`

None of the above works :(

Any help/advice/suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: You are supposed add the button to superview before setting constraints. That should be the reason why it's not working

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When I tried your code, it crashed. The problem was you were trying to add constraints before the view is initialized, adding constraints should be inside viewWillLayoutSubviews()

In any case 
I would suggest to create the button simpler, i.e.
To make the button centering the view

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width:100, heigth: 60))
btn.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

The above will automatically constraints the button to the center of the view

Hope it helps!

Comment: my above snippets is added inside viewDidLoad()

Comment: Thanks @AndreeWijaya! adding my constrains inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` function did the trick!